# Select next array in an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
[ 'markdown',
  [ 'para', 'This is a ', [ 'em', 'paragraph' ] ],
  [ 'hr' ],
  [ 'para', 'another paragragh' ] ]
```

I did something like this to match the `'hr'`:

```
for (i = 1; i < jsonml.length; i++) {
  if (jsonml[i][0] === 'hr') {
    var hr = jsonml[i]
    console.log(hr)
    // outputs: [ 'hr' ]
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to get the `[ 'para' ]` that follows `[ 'hr' ]`, in this case `[ 'para', 'another paragraph' ]`.

How to accomplish that?

Comment: `var hr = jsonml[i + 1]`?

Comment: Will it be only strings?

Comment: @ Amit Joki No, the array. Updated the question.

Comment: @thefourtheye Hey, I think that's it. Could you post an answer?

Comment: @alexchenco nope. I was asking will it be only array of strings

Comment: @ Amit Joki Yes, only array of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var found = false;
for (i = 1; i < jsonml.length; i++) {
  if (jsonml[i][0] === 'hr') {
    var hr = jsonml[i]
    console.log(hr);
    found = true;
    // outputs: [ 'hr' ]
  } else if (jsonml[i][0] === 'para' && found) {
     var para = jsonml[i];
     console.log(para);
     // process or escape the loop
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/7skhpdb7/) Supposing you want what comes after hr

```
var arr = ['markdown', ['para', 'This is a ', ['em', 'paragraph']],
    ['hr'],
    ['para', 'another paragragh']
];

var len = arr.length;
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    if(arr[i].length > 0 && arr[i][0] === 'hr' && i+1 < len){
        console.log(arr[i+1]);
        //or
        for(var j = 0; j < arr[i+1].length; j++){
            console.log(arr[i+1][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the structure of array is the same you can do this :

```
for (i = 1; i < jsonml.length; i++) {
  if (jsonml[i][0] === 'hr') {
    var hr = jsonml[i+1]
    console.log(hr)    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it will be only array of strings. So you can join it, which will flatten the array into a comma separated string.

```
var fArr = arr.join().split(","), hrIdx = fArr.indexOf('hr');
var items = fArr.slice(hrIdx).filter(function(item){
   return item == "para";
}); // returns an Array, use index for ex [0]
```